# Скачивание папок через wget

Tags: linux

Как скачать фотоальбом через wget полностью, не вытаскивая каждую картинку по ссылке???

Answer (score 6):

Ежели не изменяет склероз

```
wget -r -np url
```

Если картинки находятся в директории ниже url. `-r` или `--recursive` -- рекурсивно следовать за ссылками. `-np` или `--no-parent` -- чтобы выше не лез, а то по ссылке на home directory вытащит весь сайт. Если картинки не в поддереве url, тогда смотрите ключи -X, -I

Comment: а через vk можно скачивать фотки через wget???

Answer (score 0):

Сначала вам надо убедиться, что файл robots.txt не запрещает ботам доступ к интересующим вас ресурсам. Далее делаете примерно так

```
wget -c -p -r -l0 -np -N -k -nv http://www
```

Если что-то не выкачивается смотрите опции wget (man wget) и настраиваете по необходимости. Примеры использования [wget](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget).

Comment: А разве robots.txt может запретить доступ для wget?

Comment: Может: [robots exclusion](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Robot-Exclusion). Это не ограничение wget, а особенность. Она отключается опцией

    wget -e robots=off url...

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае – никак.

В разных системах понятие "альбом" различно, а ссылки на отдельные фотографии могут быть совершенно непредсказуемыми.

Поэтому вам придется получить полный список ссылок на отдельные фотографии альбома и загрузить фотографию с каждой из них. Что, собственно, и является "вытягиванием каждой по ссылке".